# Scrollable <ul> in an non-scrollable page - Safari on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, safari

I have an `<div>` with an fixed height of 100px. Inside the `<div>` there is a `<ul>` which has more than 100 px height. This `<ul>` should be scrollable (see the code below). This works perfectly fine in all browsers except Safari on an iPad. The page itself is then scrollable but not the `<ul>`. How do I make the `<ul>` scrollable in Safari on an iPad?

I tried body-scroll-lock (from https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock) but this is a solution for an other problem.

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div style="max-height: 100px;overflow:hidden;">
    <ul style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;display: block;overflow: hidden scroll;max-height: 100px;">
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, it's best practice to move inline styling to your CSS stylesheet whenever possible, and to add classes and/or IDs to your HTML instead.

To answer your question, you want to have `overflow: scroll` instead of `overflow: hidden` on your parent div. This will automatically hide all overflowing content, but allow you to scroll through it. You don't need any additional styling on the children!

```css
.list-wrapper {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="list-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: First I like to thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this works in all browsers except Safari on an iPad. I added a red border to the list-wrapper class and in Safari the content overflows the <div>. I made some screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/2mebCeg